# How to connect Delphi mqtt client securely to an mqtt broker?

Tags: openssl, mqtt, delphi-xe7

I want to use Delphi mqtt ssl client to connect to a secure mqtt broker for which I got a certificate (.crt). I have got an mqtt client component (pjde/delphi-mqtt on github) but don't know how to make it present the certificate during establishing connection to the broker?
I have a demo mqtt client that connects locally to a mosquitto broker without using ssl. Now I would like to try to connect it the global broker to get a subscription from my devices that already are publishing to it.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/pjde/delphi-mqtt/issues/3) (raised after the last commit) indicates there are no plans to support SSL but does mentions a potential workaround.

Comment: @Brits Why post this as a comment? It's an answer.  Get the creds...